# Valuing a binary put option

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance

I have the standard black-scholes PDE for a put option (paying no dividends):

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S^2}+rS\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}-rP=0$

Also the standard payoff for a binary put option $P_b(S,t)$ has the payoff:

$$
P_b(S,t=T)=
\begin{cases}
0 &if &S>X,\\
K &if & S<X
\end{cases}
$$

Somehow I need to show that $P_b(S,t) = K\frac{\partial P}{\partial X}$ where $P(S,t;X)$ is the value of a 'vanilla put option'.

I understand that if you differentiate the payoff of a vanilla call at expiry then you will get $0$ if $S>X$ and $1$ if $S<X$ and therefore if you simply multiply this by K you get the payoff of the binary put at expiry.

However how would you show  $P_b(S,t) = K\frac{\partial P}{\partial X}$ for all t and not just at expiry? The only hint that I have been given is that I need to differentiate the black-scholes pde with respect to X, but surely this is just zero?

Thank you in advanced